# Android emulator SDK tool update to 31.1.4 can't run

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After I updated Android emulator SDK tool to 31.1.4,it can't run,
not show up emulator.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am to getting "The emulator process for AVD 5.1_WVGA_API_29 has terminated." after the emulator was Upgraded to 31.1.4 since 2 days back.

Comment: The same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem on mac m1

1. Check in emulator directory (for example my path is */Users/ivansafonov/Library/Android/sdk/emulator*) exist file **darwin-aarch64-replace.sh**
2. if not exist, place it in this directory (link - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/android-emulator/+/master/darwin-x86_64/darwin-aarch64-replace.sh)
3. use chmod +x ***path_to_darwin-aarch64-replace.sh*** in Terminal
4. try launch emulator

Comment: I can run Android emulator  31.1.4 on myself computer with all api version, but at company's computer only can run below api version 28. I guess it because my company's computer GPU card is too old and its driver last update at Dec 2016.

Comment: The file was removed in the meanwhile you can find it in the last commit where it was removed:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/android-emulator/+/ed4d8fc6e2d9c8f97c667a78ed5c0675cb633e11/darwin-x86_64/darwin-aarch64-replace.sh